# Join result of two queries with same column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, union

I am using Oracle. I am currently working on one table with two different query output. I want to combine two output in single output, I have tried Union all and union but no luck.

```
with D as 
(
Select 
VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4 as DEPT,
SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) as ACTL_HR,
SUM(X.WAGEAMT) as ACTL_DLR,
to_char(X.APPLYDTM,'YYYY-MM') AS MONTHLY,
VP.HOMELABORLEVELDSC4 as DESCRIPTION,
NULL as DAILY,
NULL as DEPT1,
NULL as ACTL_HR1,
NULL as ACTL_DLR1
from VP_EMPLOYEEV42 VP,
WFCTOTAL X
where 
VP.PERSONID = X.EMPLOYEEID and
X.APPLYDTM between '01-DEC-18' and '31-DEC-18' and
X.EMPLOYEEID in (select personid from PERSONCSTMDATA where CUSTOMDATADEFID ='154' and PERSONCSTMDATATXT = 'USKEANE')
group by VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4, VP.HOMELABORLEVELDSC4, to_char(X.APPLYDTM,'YYYY-MM')
union all
Select 
NULL as DEPT,
NULL as ACTL_HR,
NULL as ACTL_DLR,
NULL as MONTHLY,
VP.HOMELABORLEVELDSC4 as DESCRIPTION,
to_char(X.APPLYDTM) as DAILY,
VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4 as DEPT1,
SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) as ACTL_HR1,
SUM(X.WAGEAMT) as ACTL_DLR1
from VP_EMPLOYEEV42 VP,
WFCTOTAL X
where 
VP.PERSONID = X.EMPLOYEEID and
X.APPLYDTM = '31-DEC-18' and
X.EMPLOYEEID in (select personid from PERSONCSTMDATA where CUSTOMDATADEFID ='154' and PERSONCSTMDATATXT = 'USKEANE')
group by VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM4, VP.HOMELABORLEVELDSC4, to_char(X.APPLYDTM)
)
select D.DEPT DEPT,  
SUM(D.ACTL_HR) ACTL_HR, 
SUM(D.ACTL_DLR) ACTL_DLR,
D.MONTHLY MONTHLY, 
D.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION, 
D.DAILY DAILY, 
D.DEPT1 DEPT1, 
SUM(D.ACTL_HR1) ACTL_HR1, 
SUM(D.ACTL_DLR1) ACTL_DLR1
from D
group by D.DEPT, D.MONTHLY, D.DAILY, D.DESCRIPTION, D.DEPT1
order by DESCRIPTION
```

it is giving me output like this

-DEPT-HR-DLR-MONTHLY-DESC-DAILY-DEPT-HR-DLR-

-1-12-12-11/1-Manu-NULL-NULL-NULL-NULL-

-NULL-NULL-NULL-NULL-Manu-17-1-12-12-

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have null value in any of the fields you want to group on, you will receive it as a separate row. I think you'd want to review your needed output, then we can try to paraphrase it with code to you.
Hint: you may want to look into JOIN, and group only on D.MONTHLY, D.DAILY, D.DESCRIPTION, D.DEPT1, because your DEPT column is missing in one of the tables.

Comment: I have tried with Join as well but no luck and DEPT column is there in both query as tables are same

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal (which is not quite clear to me) might be easier to achieve following this pattern:

```
with Query1 as (select fields from table where conditions are met),
     Query2 as (select fields from table where conditions are met) 
select  fields 
from Query1 
     outer join Query2 
     on Query1.identifier_for_match=Query2.identifier_for_match
where optional conditions are true
```

Note - the 'identifier_for_match' might be employeeid in your case (which would make it a required part of the Query1/Query2 resultset) - you have to look at the model and figure out how the query should combine the rows.
Also - an answer fitting your tables is easier to provide if the DDL for the tables is provided and some data for the same (including the desired output)